# Change href value in button after choose in a selector

Tags: html

I tried to set the button's link from the `querySelector`, but the value doesn't change, how do I get it set that way?

The idea is to change the button's link when I select the value in a dropdown box so I can click and open the link.

My attempt:

```
select_1
    .on("change", function(d) {
    var value_1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
    document.querySelector('#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1').href = value_1;
    });
```

The `button`:

```
<button class="button" style="width: 100%;" id="botao-de-jogo-betfair-1" href="link selector" target="_blank">Jogo Betfair 1</button>
```

When I use it in the way with `<a` I'll put it below, the value changes but it gets really weird with the link value inside the button, I'd like to just leave the button:

```
<button class="button" style="width: 100%;" ><a id="botao-de-jogo-betfair-1" href="link selector" target="_blank">Jogo Betfair 1</a></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<button>` doesn't have a `href` property, so you'll need change it's `href` attribute:

```
select_1
    .on("change", function(d) {
    var value_1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
    document.querySelector('#botao-de-jogo-betfair-1').setAttribute("href", value_1);
    });
```

Comment: Hello friend @Vanowm , now it's really set ```href```, but when I click the ```button``` it doesn't open to a new tab and opens an error page, it doesn't open the link. Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: I need to wait 6 minutes to define your answer as a solution, as soon as possible I will register, thanks!